# pass parameters from a smart capture to another landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, developer

i am modifying a SmartCapture to send captured parameters to another landing page but they do not travel through the url. it redirects fine to the other landing but the parameter is not sent, this is the code i have, thanks for the help.

```
<div class="sc-formfield-input">
 <select name="Experience" id="Experience" value="%%=v(@Experience)=%%" data-field-type="Text" required="required" data-validation-message="Please fill out this field.">
  <option value="" id="" selected="selected"></option>

  <option value="respuesta1" id="respuesta1">respuesta1</option>

  <option value="respuesta2" id="respuesta2">respuesta2</option>

  <option value="respuesta3" id="respuesta3">respuesta3</option>

 </select>
</div>

</div>

  <script>
const form = document.getElementById('smartcapture-block-7vy8vx1ex2s');
form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
  
   
  window.top.location.href = "https://www.example.com?Experience=value="%%=v(@Experience)=%%;  
  
                             
 });
 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're improperly mixing server-side code with the client-side code:

This:

`window.top.location.href = "https://www.example.com Experience=value="%%=v(@Experience)=%%;`

...should be this:

`window.top.location.href = "https://www.example.com?Experience=%%=v(@Experience)=%%";`

Keep in mind that AMPscript and SSJS are compiled *before* the page loads.  Client-side code like JavaScript is evaluated at or after the page loads.

While this will set the value on the URL value, I'm not sure this will have the effect you're intending.

Comment: Adam Sprigs lo solucione de la siguiente manera: ´´´ <script>
const form = document.getElementById('smartcapture-block-c7s68z77vq');

   form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
   let Experience=document.getElementById('Experience')
   
  
  window.top.location.href = "https://www.example.com?Experience="+Experience.value; 
  
                             
 });
 
 </script>''' pero no llegan los registros de Iphone a la Extension de Datos pueden ayudarme a solucionar para que funcione tambien con IOS por favor, Gracias